# Powershell: Trying to set value in json

Tags: powershell

I have a a json file in which I am trying to set the value of one of the nodes:

```
primaryContact : {
      loginName : null
}
```

Without going into detail, I have the path to this value stored in the value `$name`. e.g.:

```
$name = primaryContact.loginName
```

How can I change this value while referencing `$name` as part of the statement?  I have converted json properly.

This works:

```
jsonFile.primaryContact.loginName = "some value"
```

I need to do something like this:

```
jsonFile.$name = "some value"
```

If I try this last statement I get this error:

> "The property 'primaryContact.loginName' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."

Comment: You cannot reference a nested property of an object on one variable, it would require a scriptblock or a function as Mathias has shown. See [about_Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_properties?view=powershell-7.2) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$jsonFile.$name` is not going to work, because PowerShell will attempt to resolve a single property named `primaryContact.loginName` instead of first `primaryContact` and then `loginName`.

You need to dereference each member level individually - first get the value of `primaryContact` from the root object, then assign to the `loginName` property on the resulting object:

```
function Set-ByPath
{
  param(
    $RootObject,
    [string]$Path,
    $NewValue
  )

  # split path into individual member names
  $pathParts = $Path.Split('.')

  # we'll use this variable to keep track of the last member we resolved
  $object = $RootObject

  for($i = 0; $i -lt $pathParts.Length; $i++){
    $memberName = $pathParts[$i]
    if($i -eq $pathParts.Length - 1){
      # last part of the member chain, assign value and return
      $object.$memberName = $newValue
      return
    }

    # we haven't yet reach the last member, continue to get the next property in the chain
    $object = $object.$memberName
  }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
$name = 'primaryContact.loginName'
$data = '{"primaryContact" : { "loginName" : null }}' |ConvertFrom-Json

Set-ByPath -RootObject $data -Path $name -NewValue "new login name goes here"
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  So to summarize your response, this worked:

$val1 = "primaryContact"
$val2 = "loginName"

jsonFile.$val1.val2 = "some value"

Comment: @AdamCodes716 Yes, splitting it into separate variables per member name is also going to work (assuming the path is always the same depth)